# lambda expression are not supported in -source 1.6

Tags: java, android, ionic3

When I run `ionic cordova build android`, I get below error:

```
D:\Projects\ionic-bt-device-application\platforms\android\src\com\moust\cordova\videoplayer\VideoPlayer.java:73: error: lambda expressions are not supported in -source 1.6
            cordova.getActivity().runOnUiThread(() -> openVideoDialog(path, options));
                                                   ^
  (use -source 8 or higher to enable lambda expressions)
D:\Projects\ionic-bt-device-application\platforms\android\src\de\appplant\cordova\plugin\background\BackgroundMode.java:314: error: lambda expressions are not supported in -source 1.6
        cordova.getActivity().runOnUiThread(() -> webView.loadUrl("javascript:" + js));
                                               ^
  (use -source 8 or higher to enable lambda expressions)
D:\Projects\ionic-bt-device-application\platforms\android\src\de\appplant\cordova\plugin\background\BackgroundModeExt.java:175: error: lambda expressions are not supported in -source 1.6
                    getApp().runOnUiThread(() -> {
                                              ^
  (use -source 8 or higher to enable lambda expressions)
D:\Projects\ionic-bt-device-application\platforms\android\src\de\appplant\cordova\plugin\background\BackgroundModeExt.java:297: error: method references are not supported in -source 1.6
                activity.runOnUiThread(dialog::show);
                                               ^
  (use -source 8 or higher to enable method references)
4 errors
:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
```

My java version is 8, why it still asks `use -source 8`?

[image]

Comment: I don’t now how the ionic build process works. But Java 8+ has a command line parameter that you can use to set the language version to use when compiling code and generating output. The build tool used by ionic sets this to 6. To me, it looks like ionic is using Maven behind the scenes (I have had such problems with Maven build before). Can you confirm that?

Comment: Ah, since it’s android, that’s probably gradle at work, not Maven. Is there a build.gradle somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

lambda is available only from source `Java 8`.

Even though the JDK version is `1.8`, you are instructing the compiler to consider the source as `1.6`. Since `1.6` language specification does not have lambda, this is resulting in an error.

### source

> -source release
>
> Specifies the version of source code accepted.

[javac](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html)

Language features that can be supported by compiler is determined by `source` (assuming the compiler version is higher or equal to the source version)